# Unmet Dependencies and Package Broken

Tags: package-management

Getting this error even after installing packages manually as the depends warning continues.

> Packages installed :
>
> 1. libgegl-0.3-0
> 2. libumfpack5.7.1
> 3. libcholmod3.0.6
> 4. liblapack3
> 5. libgfortran3

On installing libgfortran3 the error is :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgfortran3 :Depends: 
gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I try to install gcc-5-base I get :

```
sudo apt install gcc-5-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-5-base is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Unable to understand and get pass this.

Answer (score 1):

**libgfortran3** depends on **gcc-5-base** version *5.3.1-14ubuntu2*. But you have version *5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9*. Downgrading **gcc-5-base** to required version should solve your problem.

To downgrade to required version, run this command.

```
sudo apt install gcc-5-base=5.3.1-14ubuntu2
```